Exhaustive catch clauses for errors from typed-throws
Using typed-throws (SE-0413) in Swift 6.0 (Xcode 16.0), it can correctly detect typed errors. Consider:
enum MyError: Error {
    case one
    case two
}

func funcWithTypedThrow() async throws(MyError) {…}

If you use separate catch statements for those individual MyError cases, the compiler will incorrectly conclude that the catches are not exhaustive:
// An example where typed-throw correctly infers the type of the thrown error, but
// incorrectly concludes catch is not exhaustive.

func foo() async {
    do {
        try await funcWithTypedThrow() // Swift 6.0 compiler incorrectly produces error: “Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive”
    } catch .one {
        print("one")
    } catch .two {
        print("two")
    }
}

But if I add an extra catch to silence that error, the compiler will realize that this is unnecessary and will warn that it “will never be executed”:
// In this example, I added extra `catch` to silence the above error, but now 
// the compiler now warns us that that this extra `catch` is unnecessary.

func bar() async {
    do {
        try await funcWithTypedThrow()
    } catch .one {
        print("one")
    } catch .two {
        print("two")
    } catch {  // Swift 6.0 compiler correctly produces warning: “Case will never be executed”
        print("this is required to silence 'non-exhaustive' error, but generates a 'will never be executed' warning")
    }
}

How can I get around this issue?

Sounds like a compiler bug. You should file a bug report with Apple.

Looks like it has already been reported. But hopefully the below provides a short-term work-around.

One can just catch the typed-error and then use a switch statement:
func qux() async {
    do {
        try await funcWithTypedThrow()
    } catch {
        switch error {
            case .one: print("one")
            case .two: print("two")
        }
    }
}

This seems to avoid the incorrect “exhaustiveness” checks when using separate catch clauses.

... but doesn't use the new language feature. Again, sounds like a language bug.

I'm not sure of I’m following you regarding “doesn’t use the new language feature.” It does. This calls funcWithTypedThrow from the original question, which employs typed-throw, i.e., func funcWithTypedThrow() async throws(MyError) {…}, and this sample only works because it uses this feature. But re this being a language bug, yes, I agree. There are a whole bunch of bugs/limitations in this typed-throwing pattern (and some are acknowledged in SE-0413 and discussed in the “Future Directions” section).

Sorry, my mistake. I didn't look at your alternate solution closely enough. clearly I need to read up on typed-throws.

No worries; it was subtle. Note that the switch of error here uses the concise .one and .two syntax because it knows error thrown by funcWithTypedThrow is a typed-throw of MyError. Before we used to have to catch MyError.one, etc., (with explicit error type specified at the catch block) and a catch for other error types that would never be thrown).
